# FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException when formatting a string

Tags: java

I make division in my program and result prints to the screen. There is no problem when I run the program, but when I try to launch the unit tests a receive the following error:

> java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = s, Flags = 0

On the following line:

```
String underscoreToResult = String.format("%" + (i - 2) + "s", "_");
```

Below I provide all the code related to this method :

```
private StringBuilder bodyOfMethodCalculateDivisionWhenDividentLessThanDivisor(StringBuilder result, Integer reminderInInteger, int divisor, int divident, Integer divisorMuplipliedByQuotient,
                                                                               StringBuilder lastReminder, int i) {

    String underscoreToResult = String.format("%" + (i - 2) + "s", "_");
    String resultedReminder = reminderInInteger.toString();
    result.append(underscoreToResult).append(resultedReminder).append("\n");
    String multiply = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "d", divisorMultipliedByQuontient(divisorMuplipliedByQuotient, divisor, reminderInInteger));
    result.append(multiply).append("\n");

    if (divident < divisor) {
        printLastNumber(lastReminder, reminderInInteger, multiply);
    }
    Integer tab = resultedReminder.length() - calculateAmountOfDigits(divisorMultipliedByQuontient(divisorMuplipliedByQuotient, divisor, reminderInInteger));
    String drawDashes = String.format("%" + (i + 2) + "s", createDivisor(divisorMultipliedByQuontient(divisorMuplipliedByQuotient, divisor, reminderInInteger), tab));
    result.append(drawDashes).append("\n");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the content of variable `i`? It should be bigger or equal to 3

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes Thanks. Solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `String.format("%Ns", "_");` requires N > 0.

Since you are using `String.format("%" + (i - 2) + "s", "_");` you need to ensure that the unit tests always run with `i >= 3` so that any exception is raisen.